# How can I run a Java Server in a Jenkins job without the job waiting for the Server to close?

Tags: java, ubuntu, jenkins, continuous-deployment

I'm teaching myself a bit of Java network programming and I want to use Jenkins to continuously deploy my Java Server as I develop it. I can do this no problem by starting the basic multi-threaded server in a Jenkins job but when I do, the job never finishes unless the server closes. Is there any way I can deploy the server with a Jenkins job but have the job mark it as a success when the server is deployed rather than when it terminates?

I tried writing a basic bash script to execute the server and having the Jenkins job run the script instead but the result was no different.

server.java:
https://pastebin.com/5eeUH7zk

For what it's worth, the Jenkins build step:

```sh
java server
```

I can see why Jenkins sees the job as still running, as the code is still running but I would like to mark the job as a success once the server.java is running with no exceptions.

Comment: Mind clarifying something for me? You posted the server code (assuming created by Jenkins), you're having it connect (client code I'm assuming that's not posted), and want to have it start as soon as it connects opposed to when the server ends for results?

Comment: Yes, when the server code executes, the server listens for client connections. And the Jenkins job will not end until the server stops listening for client connections. I want the Jenkins job to end as soon as the server *starts* listening for client connections without exceptions.

Comment: Apologies, The jenkins job is triggered by an unrelated trigger - a git push, but it's the graceful ending of the job that I'm concerned about. I just want it to end as a success if it's listening for client connections with no exceptions.